# sudo pgrep -f matches arbitrary strings and returns increasing pids

Tags: linux, process, ps, proc

While debugging an related issue, I noticed that pgrep was returning a PID for seemingly arbitrary command-line patterns, e.g.:

```
$ sudo pgrep -f "asdf"
13017

$ sudo pgrep -f ";lkj"
13023

$ sudo pgrep -f "qwer"
13035

$ sudo pgrep -f "poiu"
13046

$ sudo pgrep -f "blahblahblah"
14038

$ sudo pgrep -f "$(pwgen 16 1)"
14219
```

The same command without sudo returned nothing (as expected):

```
$ pgrep -f blahblahblah
```

I tried to pipe the PID to ps in order to see what the command was, but that didn't work:

```
$ sudo pgrep -f blahblahblah | xargs ps -f -p
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
```

It looks as though the process terminates too quickly. Then I tried using ps and grep, but that didn't work either (i.e. there were no results):

```
$ sudo ps -e -f | grep [a]sdf

$ sudo ps -e -o command | grep asdf
grep asdf
```

I also noticed that if I reran the command quickly enough then it seemed as though the PID was steadily climbing:

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do sudo pgrep -f $(pwgen 4 1); done
14072
14075
14078
14081
14084
14087
14090
14093
14096
14099

$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do sudo pgrep -f blahblahblah; done
13071
13073
13075
13077
13079
13081
13083
13085
13087
13089
```

As a sanity check I tried using find and grep to search the proc directory:

```
$ sudo find /proc/ -regex '/proc/[0-9]+/cmdline' -exec grep adsfasdf {} \;
Binary file /proc/14113/cmdline matches
Binary file /proc/14114/cmdline matches

$ sudo find /proc/ -regex '/proc/[0-9]+/cmdline' -exec grep adsfasdf {} \;
Binary file /proc/14735/cmdline matches
Binary file /proc/14736/cmdline matches
```

Again it seems that the PID is climbing and that the cmdline matches arbitrary strings.

I tried this out on both CentOS 6.7 and on Ubuntu 12.04 with the same results. When I tried similar experiments on my Mac the tests came back negative - no mystery processes.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's showing the `sudo` process i.e. the PID is the PID of the `sudo` process that is the parent of the `pgrep` command you are running by putting after `sudo`. As you are searching in the whole command line (by `-f`), the `sudo` process pops up in the output because the string (pattern) is also a part of the original `sudo` command.

By using the `-l` and `-a` (if your `pgrep` supports), you would get a better idea.

**Test:**

```
% sudo pgrep -af "asdf"
4560 sudo pgrep -af asdf

% sudo pgrep -lf "asdf"
4562 sudo

% pgrep -af "asdf" 
%
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why ps doesn't find the command or why pgrep on Mac OS X doesn't either?

Comment: @igal Because by the time you are running `ps`, the `sudo` process and its child are already dead. Also Mac's `pgrep` is different from GNU/Linux's one, check `man pgrep`

Answer (score 4):

It's finding your `sudo` command because the string you're searching for with the "-f" is also present in the full `ps` listing of the sudo.

Basically when you run `sudo pgrep -f xyz` then you run

```
PID1 sudo pgrep -f xyz
PID2 pgrep -f xyz
```

The pgrep command will find both, ignore itself, and report PID1 as matching.

Naturally the PIDs will increase because there's a new `sudo` command each time you run it!